# I want to mine Monero but I do not have money for a better GPU / equipment

Tags: mining

I have a notebook.

I want to mine with my GPU, but in the GUI, no GPU appears. My CPU is an i3 4th generation series U. How long can I be mining without damaging my CPU?

My notebook has a GPU: AMD R5 M330 2 GB, which I think should be more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are trying to mine for profit, that wont happen with a notebook of your spec.

Next, you cannot mine with a GPU using the Monero GUI. Only the CPU. If you want to mine with a GPU you will need to use a dedicated miner application. This said, mining with your GPU is again pointless, as the spec is very low (even if you can find a miner that supports it).

If you really want to get into mining, you are going to have to do lots more research and invest in better equipment to mine with.

Comment: Will add GPU mining is also loss; unless you have free electricity and already have a GPU.  Now mining other new coins, hold for a bit and then exchange might be a better course.

Comment: @Dave, I already state in the answer, using that GPU is also pointless. I'm also not too convinced by the rest of your comment - the user has very poor spec hardware. I also recommend keeping this on-topic (Monero) - the user is asking about mining Monero - not a general mining of any cryptocurrency - this is a Monero SE - not general cryptocurrency debate platform.